# For intrinsic semiconductors, is the gap Energy equals $E_c-E_v$ or $E_c+E_v$?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory, electrical-engineering, chemical-potential

So I have a problem with the intrinsic Fermi Level because by definition it is in the middle of the gap energy, and knowing that Eg=(Ec-Ev), we should have Ei=(Ec-Ev)/2.
But when we follow the mathematical logic of the electron and hole densities in the intrinsic semiconductor we find the Ei=(Ec+Ev)/2.
So does anyone have an idea of why we have this difference in the expression of the intrisic fermi-level?

Comment: While the level is (at non-zero T) in the middle of the gap, your first expression for $E_i$ yields the distance of the intrinsic level from either band edge. But if $E_v$ is not the zero energy reference (which it should not be), then the value of $E_i$ is given by your second expression - then $E_v$, $E_i$ and $E_c$ are all referenced to the same scale.

Comment: Note that the Fermi level of an intrinsic semiconductor is not in general at exactly half way between Ec and Ev.

Answer (score 0):

> knowing that Eg=(Ec-Ev), we should have Ei=(Ec-Ev)/2.

This formula gives the Fermi level relative to the upper edge of the valence band ($E_v$).

> But ... we find the Ei=(Ec+Ev)/2.

This formula gives the Fermi level relative to whatever reference the conduction band edge energy ($E_c$) and valence band edge energy are measured relative to.

The second formula is generally true. The first formula is only correct if you want to for some reason measure $E_c$ and $E_v$ with one reference level and then in one formula both determine $E_i$ and translate it to a different reference level.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was helpful.